# Apache Camel: Instantiate a class using its multiparameter constructor

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

How do I go about invoking a method on a class object by having it instantiated with its multiparameter constructor in a Camel route using Spring DSL with bean binding first?

For example this one:

```
package org.my.package;

public class SomeClass {
     public SomeClass() {}

     public SomeClass(String param1, String param2) {
        ...
     }

     public void doSomething() {
     }
}
```

Method invokation using the default (no-args) constructor is clear:

```
<to uri="bean:org.my.package.SomeClass?method=doSomething" />
```

Comment: Why not create the bean instance via Spring and use the instance name instead of the class name?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a class instance only using default no-argument constructor. But you can use bean properties for set class fields.

Bean

```
<bean class="org.my.pack.SomeClass" factor:bean-type="DEFAULT"
    id="SomeClass" name="SomeClass">
    <property name="param1" value="Value1"/>
    <property name="param2" value="Value2"/>
</bean>
```

Class

```
package org.my.pack;

public class SomeClass {
    public String param1;
    public String param2;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        return "Param1 - " + param1 + " Param2 - " + param2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Or you can also use annotations for method parameters and take values from headers for example (https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html)

```
public String doSomething(@Header("param1") String param1,   @Header("param2") String param2) {
    return "Param1 - " + param1 + " Param2 - " + param2;
}
```